# Add date to first element of vector to get new date and then add the next element to generate new date and so on

Tags: r, loops, date

I am trying to generate some fake data to make a dataset so I can do some analysis.  I am trying to build out a dataset where I have a haircut date and then generate other dates based on a normal skewed generation of data.  The end goal is to predict future haircut intervals.

I have built this for one single customer, but I am trying to do this over and over again for different n values so I need help building it more programatic. I have tried different loops and am coming up empty handed. I am kind of new to programming. Thanks in advance!

```
#load the library for skewed normal generation
library(fGarch) 
#set observations and generate data
n=5
set.seed(1)
days_since_last=rsnorm(n, mean = 35, sd = 5, xi = 2)
days_since_last=as.integer(days_since_last)

#generate random date to start
haircut_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2019/01/01'), by="day"), 1)

#generate new dates
haircut_date2=haircut_date + days_since_last[1]
haircut_date3=haircut_date2 + days_since_last[2]
haircut_date4=haircut_date3 + days_since_last[4]
haircut_date5=haircut_date4 + days_since_last[4]
haircut_date6=haircut_date4 + days_since_last[5]

#combine dates
date = c(haircut_date2,haircut_date3,haircut_date4,haircut_date5,haircut_date6)

#add dates to generated intervals in a dataframe
haircut_df=data.frame(days_since_last,date)
```

Comment: You could use `cumsum` to convert the vector `days_since_last` to `days_since_start`, then skip right to the last step and make a data frame where the days are `haircut_date` + `days_since_start`.

Comment: That would work if I just wanted the recent date, but I'm looking to generate the dates in between all in a dateframe mimicking a real dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation, creating the data frame right after your `haircut_date = sample...` line:

```
haircut_df <- data.frame(days_since_last = c(0,days_since_last),
                         date = c(haircut_date, haircut_date + cumsum(days_since_last)))
```

Resulting in:

```
> haircut_df
  days_since_last       date
1               0 2018-07-02
2              39 2018-08-10
3              33 2018-09-12
4              41 2018-10-23
5              28 2018-11-20
6              32 2018-12-22
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you're looking for,

```
#load the library for skewed normal generation
library(fGarch) 
#set observations and generate data
n=10
set.seed(1)
days_since_last=as.integer(rsnorm(n, mean = 35, sd = 5, xi = 2))

# Creating a variable for cumulative days since the first haircut
cumulative<-cumsum(days_since_last)

#generate random date to start
haircut_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2019/01/01'), by="day"), 1)

#initializing variable and looping for n
haircut_dates<-as.Date(x = integer(0), origin = "1970-01-01")    
for (i in 1:n)
{
  haircut_dates[i]<-haircut_date+cumulative[i]
}

#add dates to generated intervals in a dataframe
haircut_df=data.frame(haircut_dates,days_since_last)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!